# Don't calculate if a field is empty (Js calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, conditional-statements, calculator

I'm trying to limit a calculation only when a field is blank. I have many other fields that are calculated simultaneously, I would like to limit the calculation to only the fields that have not been filled.

I don't know JS very well, so I hope to be able to find help here ... Thanks for any answers, I leave more info below.

Basically everything works fine. However, when the bodyfat field is empty, the calculation for BMR and TDEE Katch McArdle and Cunningham Formula is performed.

What I am trying to do is to calculate the McArdle and Cunningham Formula fields only when the Bodyfat field contains values.

```
calculate = function()
{
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var bodyfat = document.getElementById('bodyfat').value / 100;
    var select_lvl = document.querySelector('#a_level option:checked').value; 
    
//Sex Selection Hide-Show Div// 

var sex = document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value;
document.getElementById('bmr-sexuomo').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('bmr-sexdonna').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
document.getElementById('MifflinMale').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('MifflinFemale').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
    
var bmr_mifflin_man = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) + 5;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = bmr_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_man = (bmr_mifflin_man*select_lvl);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_man').value = tdee_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var bmr_mifflin_woman = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) - 161;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_woman').value = bmr_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_woman = (bmr_mifflin_woman*select_lvl);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_woman').value = tdee_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";


 //Result BMR Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var bmr_katch = (370 + ( 21.6 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var tdee_katch = (bmr_katch*select_lvl); 
document.getElementById('tdee_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result BMR Cunningham Formula
    var bmr_cunningham = (500 + ( 22 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Cunningham Formula
    var tdee_cunningham = (bmr_cunningham*select_lvl); 
document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//This is Activity Level Radio Selection//
 var leggeros = document.getElementById('leggeros').value * 1.2;
 var attivos = document.getElementById('attivos').value * 1.375;
 var allenatos = document.getElementById('allenatos').value * 1.55;
 var Mattivos = document.getElementById('Mattivos').value * 1.75;
 var Eattivos = document.getElementById('Eattivos').value * 1.9;

}

//Reset Function
function resetFields() {

document.getElementById("bmrcalc").reset();  
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = ''
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = ''

var ele = document.getElementsByName("radiosa");
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
      ele[i].checked = false;
      
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/4n9dgbfw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse engineer it (think opposite of what you want). For example, think that calling a function when there is something in the textbox is the same as not calling a function when there isn't something in the textbox. So now you have your answer! You just need to add this in your code:

```
if (document.getElementById('bodyfat').value==""){
preventDefault();
alert("You need to enter something in the textbox first");
}
```

Thinking like this can help save a lot of time. You didn't need to know anything about Javascript for this, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code works correctly. I put it where I wanted to apply the function, so just for McArdle and Cunningham formula.

Although not necessary, I wonder why the alert message is not displayed.

Comment: Try putting the alert statement above the preventDefault statement.

Answer (score 2):

I have added a if condition for checking body fat Now it will works fine.

```js
calculate = function()
{
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value || 0;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value || 0;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value || 0;
    var bodyfat = document.getElementById('bodyfat').value / 100;
    var select_lvl = document.querySelector('#a_level option:checked').value; 
    
//Sex Selection Hide-Show Div// 

var sex = document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value || "Male" ;
document.getElementById('bmr-sexuomo').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('bmr-sexdonna').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
document.getElementById('MifflinMale').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('MifflinFemale').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
    if(bodyfat!=""){
    var bmr_mifflin_man = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) + 5;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = bmr_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_man = (bmr_mifflin_man*select_lvl);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_man').value = tdee_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var bmr_mifflin_woman = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) - 161;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_woman').value = bmr_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_woman = (bmr_mifflin_woman*select_lvl);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_woman').value = tdee_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";


 //Result BMR Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var bmr_katch = (370 + ( 21.6 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var tdee_katch = (bmr_katch*select_lvl); 
document.getElementById('tdee_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result BMR Cunningham Formula
    var bmr_cunningham = (500 + ( 22 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Cunningham Formula
    var tdee_cunningham = (bmr_cunningham*select_lvl); 
document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";
    }


//This is Activity Level Radio Selection//
 var leggeros = document.getElementById('leggeros').value * 1.2;
 var attivos = document.getElementById('attivos').value * 1.375;
 var allenatos = document.getElementById('allenatos').value * 1.55;
 var Mattivos = document.getElementById('Mattivos').value * 1.75;
 var Eattivos = document.getElementById('Eattivos').value * 1.9;

}

//Reset Function
function resetFields() {

document.getElementById("bmrcalc").reset();  
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = ''
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = ''

var ele = document.getElementsByName("radiosa");
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
      ele[i].checked = false;
      
}
```

```css
.mts-field {
    width:100%;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DCDCDE !important;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<label id="prov" class="mts-label">Peso</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="weight" name="weight1" placeholder="es: 70Kg" form="bmrcalc" required/>

<label class="mts-label">Altezza</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="height" name="height1" placeholder="es: 170cm" form="bmrcalc" required/>

<label class="mts-label">Età</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="age" name="age1" placeholder="es: 25 anni" form="bmrcalc" required/>

<label class="mts-label">Bodyfat in %</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="bodyfat" name"bodyfat1" placeholder="es: 15%" form="bmrcalc" />

<div class="mts-label">Sesso</div>

<!--Radio Button Sex-->
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male" form="bmrcalc" required>
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexuomo">Uomo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mts-radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="bmrcalc" required>
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexdonna">Donna</label>
  </div>
  
  <!--Select Activity Level-->
  <div class="container_level">
  <select class="a_level" id="a_level" name="activ_level">
    <option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
    <option id="leggeros" name="radiosa" value="1.2">Sedentario (1.2)</option>
    <option id="attivos" name="radiosa" value="1.375">Leggero (1.375) </option>
    <option id="allenatos" name="radiosa" value="1.55">Moderato (1.55)</option>
    <option id="Mattivos" name="radiosa" value="1.75">Attivo (1.75)</option>
    <option id="Eattivos" name="radiosa" value="1.9">Estremamente attivo (1.9)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!---BMR Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>


<div id="bmr-sexuomo">
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_man" name="bmr_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="bmr-sexdonna" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_woman" name="bmr_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1"  readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>
<div id="MifflinMale"> 
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_man" name="tdee_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal Uomo" min="1"  readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="MifflinFemale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_woman" name="tdee_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal donna" min="1"  readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_katch" name="bmr_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6"  readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch1"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_katch" name="tdee_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6"  readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_cunningham" name="bmr_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6"  readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunninghams"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_cunningham" name="tdee_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>


<!---Calc & Reset Button--->
<br>
<form action="" id="bmrcalc">
</form>

<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your method is definitely very fast and easy, it works correctly. However, I think I want to use the code recommended in the previous answer as I would like an alert message to indicate to the user that if Bodyfat is empty then the calculation does not start.